# Excel Formula not updating

Tags: excel

This is a weird one.

I have an excel file with formulas which is emailed back and forth between users in different countries (different language settings more than likely).
To get the formulas to calculate, you hit enable editing which calculates all the formulas in the workbook.

On windows 10, I receive a file and when I hit enable editing, the formulas do not calculate unless I manually go into each one and hit return. If I open the same file from windows 8, it calculates.

The formulas are correctly in as "custom" and automatic formula calculation is on, the sheet does not calculate if you hit calculate now. There are no circular references.

Another fix I tried was replacing all the = signs with =.

Anyone come across this issue? I do not have details of applied updates to office but I am assuming the sender and the receiver are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how that happens or why the method I am describing works, but it works for me.

Using text to columns, select fixed width but don't actually separate anything to columns and hit finish. You should get all the results of the formula.  However it is a real pain if your formulas are in many different columns.

Comment: Thanks that works, also copying and pasting formulas.